# Please help me to fix the error - mysqlclient

Tags: mysql

## pip install mysqlclient

```
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-2.1.1.tar.gz (88 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [16 lines of output]
      /bin/sh: 1: mysql_config: not found
      /bin/sh: 1: mariadb_config: not found
      /bin/sh: 1: mysql_config: not found
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-install-k_urbzi_/mysqlclient_beba1330b6804b2990fa74f56f11c3f5/setup.py", line 15, in <module>
          metadata, options = get_config()
        File "/tmp/pip-install-k_urbzi_/mysqlclient_beba1330b6804b2990fa74f56f11c3f5/setup_posix.py", line 70, in get_config
          libs = mysql_config("libs")
        File "/tmp/pip-install-k_urbzi_/mysqlclient_beba1330b6804b2990fa74f56f11c3f5/setup_posix.py", line 31, in mysql_config
          raise OSError("{} not found".format(_mysql_config_path))
      OSError: mysql_config not found
      mysql_config --version
      mariadb_config --version
      mysql_config --libs
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Please help me to fix the error.

## python -V

Python 3.9.2

## pip list

Package       Version

---

pip           22.3
pkg_resources 0.0.0
setuptools    65.5.0

Comment: What is "the error"? I don't see any error related to MySQL itself, but `mysql_config: not found` sounds like that isn't installed after all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow the installation instructions for this package.

https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/

It sounds like you're on OSX - you will need to install mysql there.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your answer instead of linking to external ressources

Answer (score 6):

Thanks. problem solved

Linux
Note that this is a basic step. I can not support complete step for build for all environment. If you can see some error, you should fix it by yourself, or ask for support in some user forum. Don't file a issue on the issue tracker.

You may need to install the Python 3 and MySQL development headers and libraries like so:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev build-essential
```

**Debian / Ubuntu**

```
pip install mysqlclient
```